# Instafeed multiple tabs image content

Tags: jquery, html, instafeedjs

How do I make my instafeed work like this?
[facebook example](https://www.facebook.com/braveandco/?sk=app_267091300008193&app_data=feed%7C991241)

I have 4 tagNames from different instagram account. That's mean I will have 4 tabs for each tagNames. When I click one of the tab, it show 12 images first because I limit it 12 images. If I click the load more button, it's showing / loading more images. If there is no more images, the load more button should hide. And I want to fade in when I click another tab. For the example, it's not fade in when I click another tab. I will use 4 different accessToken and userId in instafeed.

But right now my code is not working like that example I provided. When I click the one of the tab and then click the load more button, it will load more images, but when I go back to click another tab, it doesn't show 12 images , it's showing more that 12 images because it counts from the previous tab i click. For example, If the previous tab load more 26 images, and then I click another tab, it's show 26 images. Can someone help me with this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    tabs();
    instafeed();
});

function tabs() {
    $(".tab-content").hide();
    $(".tab-content:first").show(); 

    $("div.tabs .button").click(function() {
        $("div.tabs .button").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab-content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
}

function instafeed() {    
    var myButton = $('#load-more');
  
    var tab1 = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab1',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'shxxxyyy',
    clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
    limit: '12',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    link: 'true',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
        after: function() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                myButton.hide();
            }
        },
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        after : function() {  console.log('a'); }
    });

    // call feed.next() on button click
     $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
      tab1.next();
     });

     tab1.run();
    
    
     var tab2 = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab2',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'benice',
    clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
    limit: '12',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    link: 'true',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
       after: function() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                myButton.hide();
            }
        }
    });

    // call feed.next() on button click
     $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
      tab2.next();
     });

     tab2.run();
  
  var tab3 = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab3',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'life',
    clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
    limit: '12',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    link: 'true',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
        after: function() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                myButton.hide();
            }
        },
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        
    });

    // call feed.next() on button click
     $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
      tab3.next();
     });

     tab3.run();
  
  
    var tab4 = new Instafeed({
    target: 'tab4',
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'nice',
    clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
    limit: '12',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    link: 'true',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
        after: function() {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                myButton.hide();
            }
        }
    });

    // call feed.next() on button click
     $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
      tab4.next();
     });

     tab4.run();
  
     myButton.on('click', function() {
        // run feeds
        tab1.next();
        tab2.next();
        tab3.next();
        tab4.next();
    });

}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function(){var e,t;e=function(){function e(e,t){var n,r;this.options={target:"instafeed",get:"popular",resolution:"thumbnail",sortBy:"most-recent",links:!0,mock:!1,useHttp:!1};if(typeof e=="object")for(n in e)r=e[n],this.options[n]=r;this.context=t!=null?t:this,this.unique=this._genKey()}return e.prototype.hasNext=function(){return typeof this.context.nextUrl=="string"&&this.context.nextUrl.length>0},e.prototype.next=function(){return this.hasNext()?this.run(this.context.nextUrl):!1},e.prototype.run=function(t){var n,r,i;if(typeof this.options.clientId!="string"&&typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string"&&typeof this.options.clientId!="string")throw new Error("Missing clientId or accessToken.");return this.options.before!=null&&typeof this.options.before=="function"&&this.options.before.call(this),typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&(i=document.createElement("script"),i.id="instafeed-fetcher",i.src=t||this._buildUrl(),n=document.getElementsByTagName("head"),n[0].appendChild(i),r="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[r]=new e(this.options,this),window[r].unique=this.unique),!0},e.prototype.parse=function(e){var t,n,r,i,s,o,u,a,f,l,c,h,p,d,v,m,g,y,b,w,E,S;if(typeof e!="object"){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"Invalid JSON data"),!1;throw new Error("Invalid JSON response")}if(e.meta.code!==200){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,e.meta.error_message),!1;throw new Error("Error from Instagram: "+e.meta.error_message)}if(e.data.length===0){if(this.options.error!=null&&typeof this.options.error=="function")return this.options.error.call(this,"No images were returned from Instagram"),!1;throw new Error("No images were returned from Instagram")}this.options.success!=null&&typeof this.options.success=="function"&&this.options.success.call(this,e),this.context.nextUrl="",e.pagination!=null&&(this.context.nextUrl=e.pagination.next_url);if(this.options.sortBy!=="most-recent"){this.options.sortBy==="random"?d=["","random"]:d=this.options.sortBy.split("-"),p=d[0]==="least"?!0:!1;switch(d[1]){case"random":e.data.sort(function(){return.5-Math.random()});break;case"recent":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"created_time",p);break;case"liked":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"likes.count",p);break;case"commented":e.data=this._sortBy(e.data,"comments.count",p);break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for sortBy: '"+this.options.sortBy+"'.")}}if(typeof document!="undefined"&&document!==null&&this.options.mock===!1){a=e.data,this.options.limit!=null&&a.length>this.options.limit&&(a=a.slice(0,this.options.limit+1||9e9)),n=document.createDocumentFragment(),this.options.filter!=null&&typeof this.options.filter=="function"&&(a=this._filter(a,this.options.filter));if(this.options.template!=null&&typeof this.options.template=="string"){i="",o="",l="",v=document.createElement("div");for(m=0,b=a.length;m<b;m++)s=a[m],u=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.useHttp||(u=u.replace("http://","//")),o=this._makeTemplate(this.options.template,{model:s,id:s.id,link:s.link,image:u,caption:this._getObjectProperty(s,"caption.text"),likes:s.likes.count,comments:s.comments.count,location:this._getObjectProperty(s,"location.name")}),i+=o;v.innerHTML=i,S=[].slice.call(v.childNodes);for(g=0,w=S.length;g<w;g++)h=S[g],n.appendChild(h)}else for(y=0,E=a.length;y<E;y++)s=a[y],f=document.createElement("img"),f.src=s.images[this.options.resolution].url,this.options.links===!0?(t=document.createElement("a"),t.href=s.link,t.appendChild(f),n.appendChild(t)):n.appendChild(f);document.getElementById(this.options.target).appendChild(n),r=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],r.removeChild(document.getElementById("instafeed-fetcher")),c="instafeedCache"+this.unique,window[c]=void 0;try{delete window[c]}catch(x){}}return this.options.after!=null&&typeof this.options.after=="function"&&this.options.after.call(this),!0},e.prototype._buildUrl=function(){var e,t,n;e="https://api.instagram.com/v1";switch(this.options.get){case"popular":t="media/popular";break;case"tagged":if(typeof this.options.tagName!="string")throw new Error("No tag name specified. Use the 'tagName' option.");t="tags/"+this.options.tagName+"/media/recent";break;case"location":if(typeof this.options.locationId!="number")throw new Error("No location specified. Use the 'locationId' option.");t="locations/"+this.options.locationId+"/media/recent";break;case"user":if(typeof this.options.userId!="number")throw new Error("No user specified. Use the 'userId' option.");if(typeof this.options.accessToken!="string")throw new Error("No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.");t="users/"+this.options.userId+"/media/recent";break;default:throw new Error("Invalid option for get: '"+this.options.get+"'.")}return n=""+e+"/"+t,this.options.accessToken!=null?n+="?access_token="+this.options.accessToken:n+="?client_id="+this.options.clientId,this.options.limit!=null&&(n+="&count="+this.options.limit),n+="&callback=instafeedCache"+this.unique+".parse",n},e.prototype._genKey=function(){var e;return e=function(){return((1+Math.random())*65536|0).toString(16).substring(1)},""+e()+e()+e()+e()},e.prototype._makeTemplate=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;r=/(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/,n=e;while(r.test(n))i=n.match(r)[1],s=(o=this._getObjectProperty(t,i))!=null?o:"",n=n.replace(r,""+s);return n},e.prototype._getObjectProperty=function(e,t){var n,r;t=t.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g,".$1"),r=t.split(".");while(r.length){n=r.shift();if(!(e!=null&&n in e))return null;e=e[n]}return e},e.prototype._sortBy=function(e,t,n){var r;return r=function(e,r){var i,s;return i=this._getObjectProperty(e,t),s=this._getObjectProperty(r,t),n?i>s?1:-1:i<s?1:-1},e.sort(r.bind(this)),e},e.prototype._filter=function(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o;n=[],i=function(e){if(t(e))return n.push(e)};for(s=0,o=e.length;s<o;s++)r=e[s],i(r);return n},e}(),t=typeof exports!="undefined"&&exports!==null?exports:window,t.Instafeed=e}).call(this);
</script>


<section class="container-wrap" id="community">
 <div class="tabs">
  <button class="button active" rel="tab1">#tab1</button>
  <button class="button" rel="tab2">#tab2</button>
    <button class="button" rel="tab3">#tab3</button>
    <button class="button" rel="tab4">#tab4</button>
    
 </div>

 <div id="tab-container">
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab1"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab2"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab3"></div>
        <div class="tab-content instafeed" id="tab4"></div>
    </div>
  <button class="btn-wrap" id="load-more" href="#">
         <div class="btn">load more</div>
     </button>
</section>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/176/)

Comment: are you sure limit should be a string?

Comment: what do you mean? @Tokn

Comment: I saw this limit: '12' and thought it might need to be an int like limit: 12 , just a quick observation

Comment: yes it shows 12 for default @Tokn do you know how make it work?